# Initialize variables when they're not already declared in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use a simple try statement and a for loop statement to initialize a list of variables that were not defined previously.

Here's the code I wrote:

```py
for i in ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']:
    try:
        i
    except NameError:
        i = []
```

It doesn't work as I expect it to. After running it, I want to have var1 = [], var2=[] and var3=[] if these variables haven't been defined previously.

Here' a little more detail on what I'm trying to accomplish. A scheduled task is supposed to run every 60 seconds and I want to keep track of progress:

```py
def run_schduled():
    for i in ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']:
        try:
            i
        except NameError:
            i = []
    var1.append(random.randint(0,100))
    var2.append(random.randint(0,100))
    var3.append(random.randint(0,100))

schedule.every(60).seconds.do(run_schduled)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: This looks like an `x/y problem`.  Trying to determine name validity at run-time usually indicates that your data flow is not defined well.  Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I'm running a scheduled job, want to check if these are defined previously, so add to them, else, initialize them first.

Comment: better keep it in dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(lambda: [])
my_dict['var1'].append(1)
print(my_dict['var1'])  # prints '[1]'
```

This would not allow you to simply do `print(var1)`, however, because it would still be undefined in your local (or global) namespace as a tagged value. It would only exist in the `defaultdict` instance as key.

Another option would be to use a class:

```
class TaskRunner:
    def __init__(self, var1=None, var2=None, var3=None):
        self.var1 = var1 or [] 
        self.var2 = var2 or []
        self.var3 = var3 or []


    def run_scheduled(self):
        for i in [self.var1, self.var2, self.var3]:
            i.append(random.randrange(1, 10000000))

runner = TaskRunner()
schedule.every(60).seconds.do(runner.run_scheduled)
```

You can also use `pickle` to save instances to load later (i.e., in subsequent runs of your job).

Comment: I want to use var.append(value) later to add the results of a query. it doesn't seem to work for that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Variables that are defined in one execution of a script will not still be defined the next time you run that script, unless you save them and load them in some way. (e.g., a database, file, etc.).

Comment: @mamun gave a suggestion of how to do what you are trying to do, but if you don't want to use `globals`, then you have to find another solution that doesn't involve  setting/checking variables in the global namespace.

Comment: I'm defining them out of the function that is going to be run using schedule.run_pending(), that function supposed to check the existence of these variables and either initialize them and append to them or just append to them.

Comment: Why not just pass your variables into the function instead of trying to guess whether they were defined outside of it?

Comment: Because my understanding is that "schedule" doesn't accept any variable, it merely calls the function

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you can do this using a class.

Answer (score 0):

Try globals:

```
In [82]: for i in ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']:
    ...:     if i in globals():
    ...:         print(f'{i} already present in the global namespace')
    ...:     else:
    ...:         globals()[i] = []
    ...:

In [83]: var1
Out[83]: []
```

Comment: Any other way to avoid using globals?

Comment: If you don't want to use globals namespace then using dictionary (suggested by Thomas) is a good idea

Comment: There are some basic functions in R that allow such assignments, isn't something like assign() in R available in Python? The only way to initialize a variable is to use = sign?

Comment: @MehdiZare yes, use the globals dict, but don't do that. Just use a regular dictionary